# Newtonsoft Json: How do I remove the @ put in front of each attribute

Tags: json, xml, json.net, names

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.Net40.  When I covert the following XDocument to Json the succeeding Json is returned.

```
< lsems-Response version="1.0.0" >
< lsems-Status statusCode="000" statusText="Success" >Store Data Request accepted.< /lsems-Status >
< lsems-StoreDataResponse >< /lsems-StoreDataResponse >
< / lsems-Response >

{"?xml":
    {"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8"},
    "lsems-Response":
    {
        "@version":"1.0.0","lsems-Status":
            {"@statusCode":"000","@statusText":"Success","#text":"Store Data Request accepted."},
        "lsems-StoreDataResponse":""
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ConvertXDocToJson()
 jsonOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlOut)
End Sub
```

jsonOut is filled with the above json.

How do I remove the @ and # before each attribute?

Comment: Use the usual string replacement techniques after you convert it to string?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

string v = s.Replace("@version", "version");

Comment: I suspect that you are hitting an issue with converting a set of objects holding lists of name-value pairs, rather than having strongly typed properties, into another format. If you've already got XML you can convert from one data format to another: don't try and use object serialisation (for a start you need to decide how to handle attributes vs. elements when JSON doesn't).

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I used from regular expressions to remove the @s and #s.

Comment: The reg exp is fine - except for those cases where you have the '@' or '#' symbol as part of some legitimate content.  I've got the same problem and was hoping there was an instruction to NewtonSoft.Json to not prefix the JSON output.